# If $y$ is nilpotent in a commutative non-unital ring, must $-y$ also be nilpotent? If not, is there a counterexample?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I can see trivially the proof for the proposition if $y$ nilpotent then so is $-y$ is assuming the ring is unital (i.e. that it contains a 1), but how would it be proven assuming the ring is not unital, if it's even possible to prove?

Comment: You just have to be slightly more clever. If $y^n = 0$ then WLOG $n$ is odd, so $y^n + (-y)^n = 0$ (this does not require a unit to prove, only $(-a)b = -ab$ which follows from distributivity), so $(-y)^n = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for that! I understand now.

Comment: Or you can assume WLOG that $n$ is even so that $y^n = (-y)^n$, or you can split into cases. Either way you get the idea, the point is to prove $(-a)b = -ab$ and then apply it $n$ times.

Comment: Actually - one more question. Does the proof still require commutativity? I know that's besides the point since I only asked for the commutative case originally, but now I'm wondering if $(-y)^n = \pm y^n$ holds true for any ring. If I try to prove it, say, by induction, then I have to distinguish between even and odd cases. So I have 2 base cases to prove, $n = 1$, and n= 2. $(-y)^1 = -y$ trivially. As for $n = 2$ well, we have $(-y)(-y) = -(y)(-y)$, and then idk what to do besides $=-((-y)(y)) = --(y)(y) = y^2$. Which uses commutative property.

Comment: No, we don't need commutativity. We also have $a(-b) = -ab$ by distributivity - this does not use commutativity, we are just using distributivity in the second variable instead of the first - so $(-y)(-y) = -y(-y) = -(-y^2) = y^2$. We also have $(-y)y = y(-y) = -y^2$ so $y$ commutes with $-y$ which is another way to think about why everything is still fine here.

Comment: Thanks again! This one I sort of figured out on my own earlier and forgot to report back on, so I'm very sorry for mostly wasting your time, but your comment that (-y) and y commute was very helpful too as I was beginning to wonder about that too and I'll make sure to keep it in mind for future reference.